# SVN merging with android studio

Tags: android, svn

I have svn connected with eclipse(windows), now I wanted to import projects from eclipse to android studio(windows) using svn. When I use VCS->Checkout from version control, then also I am not able to connect with svn. I am getting the following error while checking out from svn

***cannot load  supported formats: Executable is not specified***

Comment: There is no actual question here. Please edit and write down what *exactly* is the problem. You don't know *how* to do it all? Or do you get an error when trying? What have you tried and why didn't it work (some error message) maybe?

Comment: i am getting error as " cannot load  supported formats: Executable is not specified" while checking out from svn

Comment: Put that into your question. Not in the comments. The idea is to make a good quality question. Be precise about your issue and skip the boilerplate 'hope some.... Thanks...'. I hope you get the idea..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `File->Settings->Version Control->Subversion`. Enter the path for your SVN executable in the `General` tab under `Subversion configuration directory` and un-check `Use command line client`. Also, you can download a latest SVN client such as VisualSVN and point the path to the executable (`svn.exe` in most cases) as mentioned above. That will most likely solve your problem.